# What's the meaning of this sentence in PMA of Rudin?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

While studying the principles of mathematical analysis (Rudin) alone, I faced one sentence I couldn't understand.

In 11.2 Definition (page301), it explains the "additive" and "countably additive" set function.

[image]

Below the definition, it says "we shall always assume that the range of $\phi$ does not contain both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$; for if it did, the right side of (3) could become meaningless. Also, we exclude set functions whose only value is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$".

I'm curious about the reason why the right side of (3) could become meaningless if the range of $\phi$ contains both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

In addition, I'm curious about why we need additional condition of $\vert(\phi B)\vert < +\infty$ in (9) compared to (3).
[image]

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ is not defined. $\vert(\phi B)\vert \leq +\infty$ is vacuous.

Comment: Please correct your mistypings ("counter", forgotten "both", "stide", forgotten "the range of", "$+\infty $ and 
$+\infty$",  "$\le+\infty$").

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh, I'm sorry. I corrected my mistypings. +1

Comment: @Aruralreader What's the goal-oriented question? I just faced some sentences I couldn't understand. I want to clearly understand those sentences.

Comment: @AnneBauval Now I find where I forgot "the range of". I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(3)$ we need the range to be shy of at least one of $\pm\infty$, as one can stumble onto the case when $\phi(A)=\infty$ and $\phi(B)=-\infty$, in which case $\phi(A)+\phi(B)$ is not defined.

For $(9)$, note that $A\cup B$ can be written as the union of the disjoint sets $A\setminus B$ and $B$, so that by $(4)$ one has $\phi(A\cup B)=\phi(A\setminus B)+\phi(B)$. So, if $A\supset B$, $(9)$ readily follows. In addition, one requires $\phi(B)<\infty$, as otherwise, by $(8)$ it would mean $\phi(A)=\infty$, and we have $\infty-\infty$ scenario again.

Comment: I wouldn't write "**i.e.,** $\phi(A\setminus B)=\phi(A\cup B)-\phi(B)$", precisely because this formula may make no sense, whereas the previous one always make sense.

Comment: I have one question regarding your explanation for (3). you said $\phi(A) - \phi(B)$ is not defined if $\phi(A)=+\infty$ and $\phi(A)=-\infty$. But is it $+\infty$  $-(+\infty)$ scenario? It seems like $+\infty$  $-(-\infty)$ scenario. Or is the sign of $\infty$ meaningless in this case? What's the meaning of "not defined"?  Does it mean that we can't say anything about $\infty - \infty$ regardless of which signs those $\infty$ have? Can't we discuss $\phi(A)+\phi(B)$ if $\phi(A)=+\infty$ and $\phi(A)=-\infty$ because it is not defined?

Comment: @jjw It was a typo. Fixed it.